# How to set tab widget indicator's height in android?

Tags: android, tabs

[image]

I want to reduce the height of selected tab indicator, I have used 9 patch image for it. Can you please let me know if you have any idea for the same ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have You tried to change 9patch You've used for it?

Comment: @sandrstar i changed the size of 9 patch, but result is 0.

Comment: Hmm, I mean have You tried to reduce size of scaling area using 9patch tool (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)?

Comment: @sandrstar i solved my issue using: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html  Thanks for co-operation.

Comment: Please, write the answer and accept it, so the question will be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:

```
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" />

<!-- Pressed -->
<!--    Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

<!--    Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
```

and 9 patch images put in drawable, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I use a different way of achieving custom design on tabs ,  create two xml files like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
>

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Friends" 
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
    />
```

When you set the indicator while adding a tab , use setIndicator(View view) pass this view after inflating it . This way you can achieve any custom design for tabs

Create selector files for changing background or text color on the basis of state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom layout file for highlighted and non-highlighted tabs

Answer (score 0):

Try [tabIndicatorHeight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int)) attribute.  e.g. `app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"`.  There's also a nice write-up of it here: http://panavtec.me/playing-with-the-new-support-tablayout.

Comment: This is part of tablayout(support design library), the question is asked for tabwidget...