# How to reduce Tab indicator height in android

Tags: android

I want to solve the problem like this link [How to set tab widget indicator's height in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541468/issue-in-tab-widget-indicator-height-in-android)

The user Hiren Patel  said he is using  http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ ,but I still don't know how to reduce the indicator height ,I also used 9 patch image for it .

Comment: you can look at google io app. in `SlidingTabStrip.java`.

Comment: @William follow Raghunandan's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just edit the 9-patch images manually in a photo editor. AFAIK there is no way to do it in code.